# How can I make my page refresh after a file is successfully uploaded to the backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a profile edit screen that allows a user to update a profile image and a profile banner picture using React for my frontend. Once a user image is successfully uploaded, the client receives a message saying "Profile Picture Upload Successful" or "Banner Picture Upload Successful" depending on the button that is pressed. However, once the image is uploaded, a user currently needs to click on the refresh browser button to see the updated image. How can I make it so that once the upload is complete and the user receives the response message, the browser automatically refreshes so that the user doesn't need to click the refresh button? Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

EditProfile.jsx:

```html
import '../../components/pages/styles/EditProfile.css';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import UserProfileService from '../../services/user-profile.service';
import {upload} from '../../services/upload.service';
import {FileUploader} from '../../components/FileUploader';
import axios from 'axios';
import authHeader from '../../services/auth-header';
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api';

const EditProfile = () => {
    const {user: currentUser} = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
    const [file, setFile] = useState();
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [content, setContent] = useState('');
    const [photoURL, setPhotoURL] = useState('/images/user-solid.jpeg');
    const [bannerURL, setBannerURL] = useState('/images/default-header.png');
    const [data, setData] = useState();
    const [preview, setPreview] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        UserProfileService.getProfile().then(
            (response) => {
                if (response.data.profile_img)
                    setPhotoURL(response.data.profile_img_complete);
                if (response.data.profile_banner)
                    setBannerURL(response.data.profile_banner_complete);
            },
            (error) => {
                const _content =
                    (error.response &&
                        error.response.data &&
                        error.response.data.message) ||
                    error.message ||
                    error.toString();
                setContent(_content);
            }
        );
    }, []);

    const onAddImage = (file) => {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(preview);
        if (!file) return;
        setPreview(window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
        setFile(file);
    };

    const profileImageSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);

        const result = await axios
            .post(API_URL + '/profile-image/upload', formData, {
                headers: {...authHeader(), 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
            })
            .then((res) => setData(res.data));
    };

    const profileBannerSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);

        const result = await axios
            .post(API_URL + '/banner/upload', formData, {
                headers: {...authHeader(), 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
            })
            .then((res) => setData(res.data));
    };

    return (
        <div className='page'>
            <div className='profile-container'>
                <div className='profile-card'>
                    <header className='profile-name-header'>
                        <h3>
                            <strong id='profile-name'>{currentUser.username} Profile</strong>
                        </h3>
                    </header>
                    <img src={photoURL} alt='Avatar' className='avatar'></img>
                    <img src={bannerURL} alt='Banner' className='banner'></img>
                    <div className='profile-form-container'>
                        <p id='profile-form-label'>Update your Profile Picture</p>
                        <form
                            onSubmit={profileImageSubmit}
                            className='upload-form'
                        >
                            <input
                                filename={file}
                                onChange={(e) => onAddImage(e.target.files[0])}
                                type='file'
                                accept='image/*'
                                className='profile-image-selector'
                                id='image-selection-btn'
                            ></input>
                            <button type='submit' id='data-upload-btn'>
                                Submit
                            </button>
                        </form>
                        <p id='profile-form-label'>Update your Profile Banner</p>
                        <form
                            onSubmit={profileBannerSubmit}
                            className='upload-form'
                        >
                            <input
                                filename={file}
                                onChange={(e) => onAddImage(e.target.files[0])}
                                type='file'
                                accept='image/*'
                                className='profile-image-selector'
                                id='image-selection-btn'
                            ></input>
                            <button type='submit' id='data-upload-btn'>
                                Submit
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    {data && (
                        <div className='post-message'>
                            <div
                                className={data ? 'alert post-success' : 'alert post-danger'}
                                role='alert'
                            >
                                {data.message}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default EditProfile;
```

Comment: I think you should change the behavior in the first place. Sorry, but I don't think the user should be required to refresh the page to see the updated profile picture. Don't you think this is going to be a not good user experience?

Comment: Yes, that is the behavior I am trying to figure out at the moment. I do not want a user to need to refresh, I want it to be automatic if it is possible after the user presses submit and after the response message is generated. I just am trying to figure that part out currently

Comment: Great! It is very easy to do so by the way. Just catch the `file` first. Then use the method `URL.createObjectURL(file)` and you'll get a string, and then just set this string as an `src` to any img tag. That's it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript [location.reload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

```
window.location.reload(false);
```

You can also use setTimeout to reload after few seconds like this:

```
    const profileBannerSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    const result = await axios
        .post(API_URL + '/banner/upload', formData, {
            headers: {...authHeader(), 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
        })
        .then((res) => setData(res.data))
        .then((res) => { setTimeout(() => {
                            window.location.reload(false);
                        }, 2000)

             })
     };
```

Also even without the need of reloading the page you can simply call `getProfile()` function inside `profileBannerSubmit()` and `profileImageSubmit()` this will send the call to api to get the latest details of user.

Comment: Thank you!! Would you happen to know how I can make it so that my image preview gets loaded when a user selects an image over the image that is already being displayed? I have the code for setPreview I just don't know how to set it. Should I ask this on another question?

Comment: You can share your code so that I can have better understanding. If there are many line of code you create an example on [CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or Stackblitz